# C GMP Non-Integer Powers

Tags: c, gmp

I am using the C GMP library, and I am trying to calculate a float with the mpf_t type raised to the power 1.0 / n where n is an int.  However, it seems that the pow function for this type only takes integer inputs for the power. Is there a function in this library that can do powers in the form of doubles, and if not, is there a fast algorithm I can make use of instead?

Comment: GMP's floating point support is rather limited. You should use another library such as GNU MPFR (which is based on GMP).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a function in this library that can do powers in the form of
>   doubles,

No.

> and if not, is there a fast algorithm I can make use of instead?

Yes.

The `x` to power `1.0/n` is the same as square `n` root of `x`. And there is an efficient algorithm to calculate that see: [nth root algorithm - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root_algorithm)

This is working C code which you can easily adapt for GMP.

Function:

```
void mpf_pow_ui (mpf_t rop, const mpf_t op1, unsigned long int op2);
```

- set `rop` to `op1` raised to the power `op2`, can be used in place of `dexp`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

double dexp(double a, double toN){
    double ret = 1;

    for(int i = 0; i< toN; ++i)
        ret *= a;
    return ret;
}

double nth_root(double num, int N, double precision){
    double x;
    double dx;
    double eps = precision; 
    double A = num;
    double n = N;

    x = A * 0.5;

    dx = (A/dexp(x,n-1)-x)/n;

    while(dx >= eps || dx <= -eps){

        x = x + dx;
        dx = (A/dexp(x,n-1)-x)/n;
    }

   return x;
}

int main()
{
    int N = 4;
    int A = 81.0;

    double nthRootValue = nth_root(A, N, 10e-8);
    printf("Nth root is %lf", nthRootValue);

    return 0;
}
```

Test:

```
Nth root is 3.000000
```